# Why does the compiler make space on the stack

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64

I don't know if my title is appropriate, cause my problem is: I know sometimes (f.e when I want to make use of argv[]) compiler has to arrange space on the stack for the command line arguments. Now I wrote a simple program just to see how the C compiler handles simple C arrays (actually it handles them the same way as `std::array`'s). I'm using Manjaro Linux 64 bit. C code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    //printf("%d", a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The assembly generated output (from `gcc main.c -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -o XD.s -S`):

```
    .file   "main.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $1, -32(%rbp)
    movl    $2, -28(%rbp)
    movl    $3, -24(%rbp)
    movl    $4, -20(%rbp)
    movl    $5, -16(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 6.3.1 20170109"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Now, when I uncomment `printf` statement, the code looks like this:

```
    .file   "main.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $32, %rsp
    movl    $1, -32(%rbp)
    movl    $2, -28(%rbp)
    movl    $3, -24(%rbp)
    movl    $4, -20(%rbp)
    movl    $5, -16(%rbp)
    movl    -28(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 6.3.1 20170109"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The middle part is obvious, just calling `printf`. But why did compiler put a `subq $32, %rsp` line here? Why doesn't it appear in the first example, without `printf` statement?

Comment: I don't think inspecting produced code without optimizations turned on is of any value.

Comment: Possibly $32 means ASCII `2` and it just hard-coded this value instead of calculating it? What optimizations do you have enabled?

Comment: "Why doesn't it appear in the first example, without printf statement?" it doesn't have to, since it's the (stackwise) deepest function. the version that calls printf has to save the stack, since printf itself would otherwise clobber it. But DeiDei's right, unoptimized code is unoptimized, there's no sense in asking "why" on anything inside

Comment: I think instead that, at least sometimes, un-optimized code is more straightforward (to understand) than optimized one. The first example, w/o printf(), shows already some kind of optimization. The compiler, without optimization, should have reserved the needed stack, and then write inside it. But it didn't do so, because it already knew that reserving stack was superfluous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should compile your (real) code with `gcc -S -fverbose-asm -O` if you want to look into the generated `.s` assembler file.

Notice that recent [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) require the stack pointer to be 16 byte aligned at least (in particular, for compatibility with [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) or SSE). Read also about the [Red Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_%28computing%29) (as suggested [by Zang Ming Jie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42482889/841108)).

> But why did compiler put a `subq $32, %rsp` line here? Why doesn't it appear in the first example, without `printf` statement?

Probably because without any calls to `printf` your `main` has become a leaf routine. 
So the compiler don't need to update `%rsp` to be ABI compliant (in the *called* `printf` call frame).

Comment: Output is pretty much the same, only few comments appeared at the ends of lines

Answer (score 5):

This is an optimization your compiler does. It realizes in the first case that main is a leaf function and hence it knows that the array would be safe on the stack. Whereas in the second case, the call to printf would overwrite the stack frame and hence it protects it by incrementing the %rsp.

Actually there are many such optimizations compilers do. For instance the ABI specifies that the stack must be 16 bytes aligned before call and the frame created in such a way that the %rsp is 16 bytes aligned. But in case the function doesn't call any other function or doesn't use any SSE instructions (one example of instruction which requires aligned stack frame) it breaks the ABI requirements.
These are really just micro optimizations done to save every byte possible.

Answer (score 4):

I added comments to each line of assembly.

```lisp
main:
    pushq   %rbp            ; save old stack frame
    movq    %rsp, %rbp      ; rbp = stack frame of this function
    subq    $32, %rsp       ; 32 bytes reserved on stack for local variable(s)
    movl    $1, -32(%rbp)   ; a[0] = 1 (at rbp-32 == rsp)
    movl    $2, -28(%rbp)   ; a[1] = 2
    movl    $3, -24(%rbp)   ; a[2] = 3
    movl    $4, -20(%rbp)   ; a[3] = 4
    movl    $5, -16(%rbp)   ; a[4] = 5 (rbp-16 == rsp+16)
        ; remaining 12B from rbp-12 to rbp-1 is not used ("wasted")
        ; but it works as "padding" to have correctly aligned rsp for printf
    movl    -28(%rbp), %eax ; eax = a[1]
    movl    %eax, %esi      ; esi = a[1] (argument for printf)
    movl    $.LC0, %edi     ; edi = format string pointer
    movl    $0, %eax        ; eax = 0 (zero FP/SSE arguments)
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax        ; return value of main
    leave                   ; restore stack frame and exit main
    ret
```

Answer (score 2):

rsp is used to pass frame point to inner calls, if a function doesn't call other function, it don't need to adjust rsp offset.

NOTE: There is a 128-byte area beyond the location pointed to by %rsp called red zone. Even if the function doesn't adjust rsp, its red zone is still protected.

Comment: Okay, but then I only need space for 2 printf arguments, so that would be 2x8 bytes = 16

Comment: This is very imprecise. rsp is the stack pointer, and serves to reserve memory. May be that in the OP's environment you can write to the stack without lowering rsp, but in other environments this would be destructive.

Comment: @Frynio the array itself 5*4=20B is there too, it's local variable, so it resides in stack memory. Upon return from `main` the stackframe is thrown away, thus any local POD variable is "freed" automagically (although objects would need destructor call first, so there would be more assembly code before releasing stack frame and `ret`). Actually the printf doesn't space for arguments, you are using 64b ABI where arguments are sent in registers (when possible, like here).

Comment: @Frynio: no. You need to lower rsp in order to preserve the local data of the function. In this case, an array of 5 integers. When calling printf(), arguments to it must be prepared/passed, sometimes on the stack (via push and similar), or, as in this case, via registers.

Comment: @Frynio amd64 cedcl calls arguments are carried by rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx (or edi, esi, edx, ecx)

Comment: Okay, I get it, but why exactly 32 then?

Comment: @Frynio look at the answer from Basile. If stack alignment is required, rsp always moves off by that amount at minimum. If 20 bytes are needed, 32 are used to keep alignment, because 16 would be too little.